# Problem to load a RecyclerView with Firebase data (No setter/field)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, recyclerview-layout

I need to fill a recyclerview with the data I have stored in FireBase but I don't get it and I am not able to find the error.

Adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UsuarioHolder holder, int position) {
    Aviso user = avisos.get(position);
    holder.latitud.setText(String.valueOf(user.getLatitud()));
    holder.longitud.setText(String.valueOf(user.getLongitud()));
    //holder.getNombre().setText(listMensaje.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.usuario.setText(user.getUsuario());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return avisos.size();
}
public static class UsuarioHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView usuario,longitud,latitud;
    public UsuarioHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        usuario=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvUsuario);
        longitud=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLongitud);
        latitud=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLatitud);
    }
}
}
```

Object

```
public class Aviso {
    private Double latitud;
    private Double longitud;
    private String usuario;

    public Aviso() {
    }

    public Aviso(Double latitud, Double longitud, String usuario) {
        this.latitud = latitud;
        this.longitud = longitud;
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
    public Double getLatitud() {
        return latitud;
    }
    public void setLatitud(Double latitud) {
        this.latitud = latitud;
    }
    public Double getLongitud() {
        return longitud;
    }
    public void setLongitud(Double longitud) {
        this.longitud = longitud;
    }
    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }
}
```

activity

```
@Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            aviso.removeAll(aviso);
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot:
                    dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Aviso user = snapshot.getValue(Aviso.class);
                aviso.add(user);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

JSON

```
{
  "aviso" : {
    "-LT9trd7ej8aLhPlDVsM" : {
      "latitud" : 37.7,
      "longitud" : -122.0999983,
      "usuario" : "login2"
    },
    "login2" : {
      "latitud" : 32,
      "longitud" : -122.0999983,
      "usuario" : "login2"
    }
  },
  "chat" : {
    "-LT9WsU8whS5ZPONAosl" : {
      "fotoPerfil" : "",
      "hora" : 1544217397371,
      "mensaje" : "hola que tal",
      "nombre" : "Hola ",
      "typemensaje" : "1"

  }
}
```

Thank you very much, I'm blocked with this topic

Comment: What's the problem with this code? Is there an error? A stack trace? Did you run it in a debugger? If so, what happened that you didn't expect?

Comment: Is it a fragment or activity in which you have recyclerview? Do you get data into app but not into recyclerview, or you don't get data in app at all?

Comment: What is the referece that you using? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Aviso Class. Aviso Json Object Contain two another Json Object

- **LT9trd7ej8aLhPlDVsM**
- **login2**

so either you can parse it manually or your have to modify you Aviso Class you, can try this.

```
  for (DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String jsonString = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
            JSONObject avisoJsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("aviso");
            Iterator<String> keys = avisoJsonObject.keys();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                if (avisoJsonObject.get(key) instanceof JSONObject) {
                    if (avisoJsonObject.getJSONObject(key).get("latitud") != null) {
                        JSONObject data = avisoJsonObject.getJSONObject(key);
                        Aviso user = new Aviso(data.getDouble("latitud"), data.getDouble("longitud"), data.getString("usuario"));
                        aviso.add(user);
                    }
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```